# Local tensorflow.js won't work as a module in webworker

Tags: javascript, module, web-worker, tensorflow.js

I'm using a local copy of tensorflow.js `tfjs.js` in an experimental setup. All is browser side, no node.js.

I want to move the tensorflow functionality to it's own thread in a webworker since it's heavy on the browser. However the way I got the tensorflow module to work in a worker does not make sense:

This was the initial idea:

```
//main.js
let predictor = new Worker ('prediction_ww.js', {type: 'module'})

//prediction_ww.js
import * as tf from "tfjs.js"
```

But this produces the following error when I start execution (note: 'loadGraphModel' is a method in tensorflow.js):

```
prediction_ww.js:44 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: tf.loadGraphModel is not a function...
etc...
```

After testing without a real idea of what I'm doing I get this code, without the `type: 'module'` to work:

```
//main.js
let predictor = new Worker ('prediction_ww.js')

//prediction_ww.js
var tf = import ("./tfjs.js")
```

I would like to understand why this works but not the case using module which my reading suggests should be the correct way of using an external module in a webworker on the browserside.

Also I noticed it only works using the `./` before the filename which I also don't understand why.

I use Chrome 96 on macOS 10.14.

Comment: May you make sure that tensorflow doesn't rely on APIs not accessible inside a web worker?

Comment: At this point I don't know. Would that make any difference since it seems the code is working in the way I set things up? Or do you mean my way of initializing this reverts execution back to the main thread?

Comment: One other thing to answer is whether ESM works inside web workers? I'm not sure if they're modules. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: OK, I'm not sure what that means. Maybe I should rephrase the question and ask if the way I got this to work is the correct way of setting an extarnal js-library to work insida a web worker provided the library in question does not rely on stuff incompatible with web workers. I would think it's a failry common idea to use external code in webworkes, as one would do in the main thread. Maybe I got this wrong?

Comment: Yeah I misunderstood the question. You'd like to know why _it does work_?

Comment: Considering the complications you mention the main question is maybe more like: *Are modules supposed to work in webworkers and if so, how do I set them up?* As a not so experienced Javascript coder I can't make sense of this.

Answer (score 2):

First, `tfjs` works just fine in a web worker unless you try to use specific functions that rely on DOM (e.g. can't use `tf.browser.*` methods) - and that's not the case here.

When you say *local* `tfjs.js` - which variation of `tfjs` is that? it ships as many variations and only ESM modules can be loaded using `{type: "module"}`

Default `tf.js` is NOT ESM, but `tf.es2017.js` is

Comment: I'm not sure which Tensorflow.js I downloaded (it was a while ago) so I'll have to look into that. Great advice.